# Post request to store a highscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api, post, backend

I am building a simple game app for practice with a rails backend and a react front end, I want there to be a way to store the last 5 scores from a user and display them on a high scores page.
I am just having trouble following how to build this out. I realize I will have a component in my frontend with all the logic for putting the scores/username in order and displaying them.
However I am stuck on how the scores/username themselves can be sent to my database and stored to later be used.

I don't want to store them in a local state in my frontend.

I am looking to practice with post requests to an api and storing data in a database!
any help in a walk through process of this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's build a model called `PointHistory (user_id: bigint, amount: integer, created_at: datetime)`

```rb
# app/controllers/point_histories_controller.rb

def index
  @point_histories = PointHistory.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
  render json: {status: :success, data: @point_histories}, status: 200
end
```

And in your React component, you call that API endpoint to fetch the data and show it out.

If you have any question, please feel free to ask. I will answer it all.

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding scores. Id like a user to be able to play the game, type in their name and it be stored in a backend database that can be displayed in a frontend component.

Comment: You can create a PointHistory#Create API to store scores in the database you want

Comment: Ive created a score database within my api,  Im using thunk middleware and my action creator is returning the information in the console. is it bad practice to make a post request in an action creator?